# Order of growth in two loops

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

What is the order of growth in the following code?

```
   int result = 0;
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i *= 2)
      for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
         result++;
```

The answer is supposed to be n, but I'm not sure how to figure that out.
How can I calculate the order of growth in these loops?

My assumption would be that the outer loop runs (log n + 1) times. The inner loop is dependant of the outer loop, since it uses i. But how is this equal to n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time the inner loop executes for a given `i`, it has `i+1` iterations.

Since i has the values 2^0, 2^1, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4, ...

The total number of iterations of all the executions of the inner loop is bound by

2^0 + 1 + 2^1 + 1 + 2^2 + 1 + ... + 2^k + 1 where 2^k <= n

that's bound by

```
2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^k + logn
```

Now we have the sum of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series):

```
2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^k = 2^(k+1) - 1 <= 2n - 1 since 2^k <= n
```

Therefore you get a bound of:

```
2n - 1 + logn
```

which is `O(n)`.